# Auto row-adjust in excel, python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

with cells containing text of different fontsizes, how can we adjust the row height automatically using openpyxl in python so that the text inside any cell can be seen properly.

Answer (score -1):

Use `wrap_text` property of openpyxl:

```
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        cell.style.alignment.wrap_text=True
```